# Quarkus smallrye kafka UI unexpected error

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

1. Nothing fancy just a simple quarkus app with smallrye kafka extension. Message is successfully published and the topic can be seen on the Kafka UI dev console.
   [image: Topic is seen]
2. But as soon as I click on the topic, I get the below issue:
   [image]

```
2022-12-20 17:15:57,522 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HTTP Request to /q/dev/io.quarkus.quarkus-kafka-client/kafka-admin failed, error id: a9c99feb-242c-4120-9236-cca91d277285-10: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12.<init>(ImmutableCollections.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.List.of(List.java:812)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaTopicClient.partitions(KafkaTopicClient.java:253)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaTopicClient.assertRequestedPartitionsExist(KafkaTopicClient.java:232)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaTopicClient.getPagePartitionOffset(KafkaTopicClient.java:174)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaTopicClient_ClientProxy.getPagePartitionOffset(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaUiUtils.getOffset(KafkaUiUtils.java:188)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.KafkaUiHandler.handlePost(KafkaUiHandler.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.AbstractHttpRequestHandler.doHandle(AbstractHttpRequestHandler.java:50)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.AbstractHttpRequestHandler.handle(AbstractHttpRequestHandler.java:33)
    at io.quarkus.kafka.client.runtime.ui.AbstractHttpRequestHandler.handle(AbstractHttpRequestHandler.java:9)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:140)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.next(RoutingContextWrapper.java:200)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.doEnd(BodyHandlerImpl.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl$BHandler.end(BodyHandlerImpl.java:335)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:246)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpEventHandler.handleEnd(HttpEventHandler.java:76)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.onEnd(Http1xServerRequest.java:581)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.lambda$pendingQueue$1(Http1xServerRequest.java:130)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:239)
    at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:129)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest.handleEnd(Http1xServerRequest.java:562)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:76)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:153)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.onEnd(Http1xServerConnection.java:191)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.onContent(Http1xServerConnection.java:181)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleOther(Http1xServerConnection.java:161)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:149)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
INFO] in.co.lynk:order-producer:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-core:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jakarta.interceptor:jakarta.interceptor-api:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-ide-launcher:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-development-mode-spi:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.config:smallrye-config:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.config:smallrye-config-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-expression:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-function:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-classloader:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.smallrye.config:smallrye-config-common:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager-embedded:jar:1.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:2.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logmanager:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:jar:22.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:jar:1.5.4.Final-format-001:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-runner:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-fs-util:jar:0.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-datasource:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.agroal:agroal-api:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.agroal:agroal-narayana:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jboss-transaction-spi:jar:7.6.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.agroal:agroal-pool:jar:1.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-credentials:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-narayana-jta:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-transaction-annotations:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-mutiny:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation-storage:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:mutiny-smallrye-context-propagation:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation-jta:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-converter-api:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-converter-mutiny:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta:jar:5.13.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.resource:jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.narayana.jts:narayana-jts-integration:jar:5.13.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-graalvm:jar:5.6.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3-b02:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.3-b02:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:quarkus-local-cache:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-caffeine:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive-jackson:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive-common-types:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.quarkus:quarkus-netty:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- com.aayushatharva.brotli4j:brotli4j:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- com.aayushatharva.brotli4j:native-linux-x86_64:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-haproxy:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-latebound-mdc-provider:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.smallrye:smallrye-fault-tolerance-vertx:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive-vertx:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.vertx:vertx-web:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.vertx:vertx-web-common:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.vertx:vertx-auth-common:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-core:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-runtime:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:vertx-mutiny-generator:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.vertx:vertx-codegen:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive:resteasy-reactive:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:commons-logging-jboss-logging:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-security-runtime-spi:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-vertx-context:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-constraint:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http-dev-console-runtime-spi:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus.security:quarkus-security:jar:1.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-web-common:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-auth-common:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bridge-common:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-uri-template:jar:2.28.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.vertx:vertx-uri-template:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.crac:org-crac:jar:0.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish:jakarta.json:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka-api:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-context:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-semconv:jar:1.19.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:mutiny:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.2-1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.vertx:vertx-kafka-client:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.vertx:vertx-core:jar:4.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.85.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-mutiny-reactive-streams-operators:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive-streams-operators:microprofile-reactive-streams-operators-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive-streams-operators:microprofile-reactive-streams-operators-core:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:mutiny-reactive-streams-operators:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kotlin:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-annotation:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-health:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.microprofile.health:microprofile-health-api:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-provider:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-api:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:9.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-toml:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-datasource-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus.arc:arc:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation:microprofile-context-propagation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.smallrye:smallrye-open-api-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi:microprofile-openapi-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.microprofile.config:microprofile-config-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.smallrye:jandex:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-swagger-ui:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-quartz:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler-kotlin:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler-api:jar:2.15.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.cronutils:cron-utils:jar:9.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:provided
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-app-model:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.smallrye.common:smallrye-common-io:jar:1.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.5:test
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-test-common:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-core-deployment:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.aesh:readline:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.18:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.aesh:aesh:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus.gizmo:gizmo:jar:1.4.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-class-change-agent:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-devtools-utilities:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-builder:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:2.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.3.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1-jre:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.26:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.8.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-connector-basic:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-wagon:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5-properties:jar:2.15.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.1:test
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.19:test
[INFO] |     \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |        \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:test
[INFO] \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:3.0.9:test
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:3.0.9:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.13:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO]    +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:3.0.9:test
[INFO]    |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]    \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO]       \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:test
```

Does anyone have any clue what is causing this problem? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have isolated the issue to my custom ObjectMapperCustomizer that I needed to convert all json payloads to use snake_case.

```
@Singleton
public class ObjectMapperCustomizer implements io.quarkus.jackson.ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    public void customize(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(NON_NULL);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(SNAKE_CASE);
    }

}
```

This apparently has affected the kafka ui running as one of the dev services. How do I isolate kafka dev services from this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please open an issue on Github